# Can't scroll to top or left of flex when using align-items:center or justfiy-content:center

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, styles

I am using **display:flex** in a parent element with **justify-content:center** and **align-items:center** and the parent element having multiple children. so when I want to scroll it to extreme top or extreme left, it doesn't work, its only scrolling from center to end. I want it to show center elements for the first time (which is showing) but should scroll from start to end. (Same scroll issue for flex-end).

Example Code:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Give more clarification of your problem, and insert code, pls.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes sure, I will update my question.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I want a scrollable element, whose elements should show at center on first time but I can scoll the overflow elements to start to end but overflow:scroll not working properly with display:flex. specially when using center or flex-end property.

Comment: If I understand you right, you only chance is to use JS or anchors to display centered elements instead at the top element by default. It has nothing to do with overflow but standard browser ebhavior. A website is read from top to bottom. If the center content should be displayed by default instead of the top content you have to either give it an anchor that the page is jumped to it by default or you have to use tricky JS and use a technique like scroll-snap

Comment: @tacoshy But I am creating a web app in angular, so there where so many parent and child elements will be present(like in hundred or thousand). So I don't think JS is the good solution for that. is there any way to do it with css. now I have edited my question and you can see the issue by running the code snippet

Comment: I've never seen a site start with a scroll element in the middle except with hash or javascript

Comment: Additional clarification,
the scroll line always starts in the top left corner so it is impossible to scroll automatically with css

Comment: @FSodic How can I use js for multiple dynamic elements? I am using angular 7 framework. If possible, can you share example code for that?

Comment: but I also want to center the elements if they are not overflowing their parent element, which is not possible in js I guess